# How to run all previous notebooks in a folder in Databricks?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I found this is a very common need to run all previous notebooks in Databricks:

- as the previous Cluster is not functional and needs to create a new one on the other day. This is common in community instances of Databricks. https://community.cloud.databricks.com/
- to get to the same state as previous, it would need to run all previous notebooks
- now I can only do that manually one by one

The solution would need to:

- clean all the results and states on each notebook
- and run all previous notebooks by order
- somewhat similar to the function "run all above" inside a notebook

Answer (score 1):

Found a way or two ways to do that:
https://medium.com/datasentics/how-to-execute-a-databricks-notebook-from-another-notebook-b4a5b093cb2

For Databricks community version, it can only use the way of `%run ..`

For example, for Azure Databricks, I can create a new notebook with a bunch of cells like:

```
dbutils.notebook.run('00_ingest_raw', timeout_seconds=0)
```